# I receive an error(ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTERSECT") in my postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I receive an error(`` ERROR: syntax error at or near "`INTERSECT`" ``) in the SQL query, can someone help me to fix it?

The query is below:

```
SELECT *,
case when (Sum("col_name") OVER (INTERSECT select("col_name")) / Sum("col_name") OVER (All("col_name")))> 0.1 
then "col_name" else 'Other' end
FROM #table# AS "table"
```

Thanks in advance!!

I've tried to fix the query, nothing helped :(

Comment: What's your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [INTERSECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) operator has the following syntax:

> query1 INTERSECT [ALL] query2

and

> returns all rows that are both in the result of query1 and in the
> result of query2. Duplicate rows are eliminated unless INTERSECT ALL
> is used

You are using it in [WINDOW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) function which is incorrect. I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN COUNT("col_name") OVER (PARTITION BY  "col_name") * 1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER () > 0.1 THEN CAST("col_name" AS VARCHAR(12)) ELSE 'other' END
FROM #table#
```

which for every row is giving the "colum_name" value if the count of the value is greater then 10% of the total rows in the table, otherwise - 'other'.

Also, you can replace the `COUNT` with `SUM` if that's what you need.

```
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN Sum("col_name") OVER (PARTITION BY  "col_name") * 1.0 / Sum("col_name") OVER () > 0.1 THEN CAST("col_name" AS VARCHAR(12)) ELSE 'other' END
FROM #table#
```